# Android CSS scrollbar offsets according to distance from top border -- why?

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, overflow

I'm writing an HTML5 app for Android/Chrome and iPad/Safari.  In it I create a DIV with overflow:auto and top:XXpx.  Here is a sample:

```
<div id="divVerticalList" style="width: 180px; height: 600px; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 200px;">
  <div id="divVerticalListUL" style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 93%;">
    <ul id="distDV" class="pickList">
      <li id="distDVu30" value="30" class="evenLi">+30</li>
```

If top:0px then the divVerticalListUL appears at the top of the screen and the scrollbar operates from the top of divVerticalListUL.  The scrollbar is properly sized for showing the fraction of the list content in the DIV height.  Scrolling through the list is OK.

If top:100px then the DIV appear at 100 pixels down and the scrollbar begins 100 pixels down from the start of the DIV.  It should begin where the DIV begins.  The scrollbar height is what it should be.  When I scroll through the list the scrolling goes through the expected height, but 100px too low.  The bottom of the scrollbar extends below the bottom of the DIV.

The obvious workaround is to use top:0px.  Is there a better answer?

Thanks in advance,
Jerome.

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to debug this without seeing a live demo, but here goes.  I am making an assumption that you are setting top:0px on divVerticalList, this makes sense you have set the divVerticalList list to be position absolute, which means it is setting the top of the divVerticalList to 100px in document co-ordinates.  This would mean that divVerticalListUL is also 100px from the top of the document.

The height calculation of 93% is based on 93% of 600px, so when you set top:100px, the end of your viewport is 700px (600 + 100px) but you are still 600px high.  The inner element is still sized to 93% of 600 = 558px which in most cases is bumped off the screen still.

Comment: I said that when (top: 0px) that the scrollbar is OK, starting near the top of the div.  When (top: 100px) the scrollbar starts 100px below the top of the div.  That is wrong, it should start at the top of the div.  The scrollbar has the correct height, but it is now offset w.r.t. the div.  The problem isn't the div being too high, but that the scrollbar sticks out below the div by about 100px.  Change things to (top:300px) to get even more drama.

Comment: Again, please show us a demo of this failing, when I tried your code I didn't see a single problem.